# RaspberryPi Python IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, indentation

When running the code below I get an indentation error but I can't seem to find the issue. I'm new to python so I'm sure it's something glaringly obvious but I can't see it.

```
#Import modules to send commands to GPIO pins
from subprocess import call
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

#Define function to keep script running
def loop():
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)

#Define function to run when interrupt is called
def shutdown(pin):
call('halt', shell=False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) #Set pin numbering to board numbering
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN) #Set pint 7 as input pin
GPIO.add_event_detect(7. GPIO.RISING, callback=shutdown, bouncetime=200) #Setup inteript to look button press

loop()
```

When run I get this error:

```
File "/home/pi/PiSupply/softshut.py", line 8
    while True:
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Please help, I've spent far too long on this and I can't seem to find the indentation error it's referring to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [all online samples I was able to found](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), whole function body has to be indented. Where exactly have you found constructs, where function bodies are not indented?

Comment: The error you posted answers your question ...

Comment: "Please help, I've spent far too long on this and I can't seem to find the indentation error it's referring to." - in your own words, what do you think an "indentation error" actually is? What do you suppose "indentation" is? What do you suppose is the correct indentation for that line, and why? (Hint: where the code says `time.sleep(0.2)`, why does it have spaces before it? What is the rule that tells you, that there should be spaces there? If you **apply that same rule** to the line with the problem, what do you conclude?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

After a function, you need to indent your code. Same on `shutdown` function.

Comment: Thankyou, saved my day, I knew it had to be something easy

Comment: With pleasure .

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent while True. In Python you have to indent code that belongs to a definition or loop. The code in def loop() needs to be indented.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I knew it was something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

It means the compiler expected an indent before the word `while`.